# Tab key on ZSH terminal in Catalina keeps running "bundle exec jekyll serve"

Tags: terminal, keyboard, catalina, zsh, ruby

I don't have jekyll installed on my system

```
➜  ~ Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

➜  ~ which jekyll
jekyll not found
➜  ~ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ which bundle 
zsh: correct 'bundle' to '.bundle' [nyae]? n
/usr/bin/bundle
```

Every time I press Tab key on the terminal to navigate the files and folders it returns

"Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory". How do I resolve the issue?

Edit: Resolved  I had an alias as `exec="bundle exec jekyll serve"` which was messing up the navigation.

Comment: Try going to .zshrc file and see if that is defined somewhere in the file. The file is located in your home directory.

Comment: Crap, right, I had an alias as exec="bundle exec jekyll serve" Thanks

Comment: If i post that as an answer will you accept it?

Comment: Sure will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the .zshrc file in your home folder and check if a command like that is listed.  If so delete it. The .zshrc file gets executed every time you open a terminal window.